# imagecreatefrompng() says that the URL returned a 404 error

Tags: php, http, url, http-status-code-404, gd

i am trying to create a PNG resource from an image on a remote server, for that i use

```
$im = imageCreateFromPng('http://textures.minecraft.net/texture/7235ea086a4604e15e513c4add3935d64f23c535f9f62917c6d4886705ac8cf');
```

but when i execute the script it gives me this error:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(*url*): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I tried to access the url above with my browser and the image loaded just fine, then i made a head request to that URL to see if the server sends a 404 header but i found out that it does not. so i have no idea how to solve this issue, thank you for reading.

**EDIT**
everything works just fine on another server i own, just not this one.

Comment: My best guess is that you have `allow_url_fopen` set to false on that server

Comment: Bogdan Kuštan Nope, i just made sure it's on, still does not work.